# How I send custom msgs to ejs and access while using passport-local-mongoose , passport-local ,passport, session when authentication fails in any case

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

Here are my register and login setup which I used to authenticate users using passport-local-mongoose , passport-local ,passport, express-session

```
    app.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
        User.register({username:req.body.username},req.body.password,(err,user)=>{
            if(err){
                res.redirect("/register")
            } else{
                passport.authenticate('local')(req,res,()=>{
                    res.redirect("/secrets")
                })
            }
        })
    });

    app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
        const user=new User(req.body)
        req.login(user,(err)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                res.redirect("/login")
            } else{
                passport.authenticate('local')(req,res,()=>{
                    res.redirect("/secrets")
                })
            }
        })

    })
```

Whenever authentication is performed and in the following cases if username already exists(register) , incorrect username or password(login) these application don't send custom error messages like username already exists, wrong id/password .

How can I implement that and send those messages to ejs file and how can I access them in my template?